# Selenium - cannot find youtube search bar

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, time, youtube

**Error message :**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: input.ytd-searchbox
```

I keep getting this error, even though i added a sleep command from other solutions for the page to load dynamically with javascript, but still it cannot find it?

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver  
firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
firefox.get("https://www.youtube.com")
element = firefox.find_element_by_css_selector("ytd-mini-guide-entry-renderer.style-scope:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)") # opens subscriptions
element.click()
time.sleep(10) # wait for page to load before finding it
searchelement = firefox.find_element_by_css_selector('input.ytd-searchbox') # search bar

searchelement.send_keys("Cute Puppies")
searchelement.submit()
```

Comment: Check for waiting functions selenium has out of the box
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed the CSS Selector. You did that wrong here.
Umm... how i did that? Well there's an easy trick for selecting CSS Selectors.

1. Type the tag name first. In your case it's `input`.
2. If there's an `ID` present here, type the ID name with `#` on it. So
   as i did : `#search`.
3. If there's a `class` there, then use `.` before it's name. For
   example `.search`.

Try this. It's working :

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver  

firefox = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\intel\Downloads\Setups\geckodriver.exe')
firefox.get("https://www.youtube.com")

element = firefox.find_element_by_css_selector(".style-scope:nth-child(1) > #items > .style-scope:nth-child(3) > #endpoint .title") # opens subscriptions
element.click()

time.sleep(10) # wait for page to load before finding it

searchelement = firefox.find_element_by_css_selector('input#search') # search bar

searchelement.send_keys("Cute Puppies")
searchelement.submit()
```

Comment: why didn't the css selector work when i used inspect element of the search box?

Comment: When i used inspect to copy the Selector then it returned me `#search` only. But no need to get complicated here. If in future you struggle with `CSS Selectors` then use this chrome extension : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/get-unique-css-selector/lkfaghhbdebclkklgjhhonadomejckai @MahdeenSky

Comment: ty so much thats really useful